Why is my horizontal rule element not visible in the tooltip?
How can I customize the tooltip to my liking? Nothing I try seems to work.
formatter: function() {
    let total = 0;
    let tooltipHtml = `<strong>${this.x}</strong><br/>`;

    const colors = ['#857BFB', '#AAA1FC', '#CDC6FD', '#F1B403']; 
    let colorIndex = 0; 

    this.points.forEach(point => {
        total += point.y;
        const color = colors[colorIndex % colors.length]; 
        tooltipHtml += `<span style="color: ${color}">&#9679;</span> ${point.series.name}: ${Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 0, ',', ' ')} ₽<br/>`;
        colorIndex++;
    });

    tooltipHtml += '<hr style="border: none; border-top: 1px solid #000; margin: 5px 0;">';

    tooltipHtml += `<strong>Итого: ${Highcharts.numberFormat(total, 0, ',', ' ')} ₽</strong>`;
    return tooltipHtml;
}


Is the <hr> the only thing which does not work? If so, does it show if you remove the style attribute?

Please create a simplified demo using the editor. it's going to be difficult to help with what we can't see. See [ask].

Please let us know what exactly doesn't work so we can help you. Here's your demo with one small fix as this.points doesn't exists we should replace it with this.series.points: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xqcftbv1/
